# GROUP BY to return entire row

Tags: sql, group-by

I want to return the most recent ten (complete) rows from a table, but ensuring they all have unique 'alternate_id's.  If there are two in the top ten with the same alternate_id I don't care which I take, but I want one of them!  I thought I'd use group by as follows:

```
select * 
from track_history_items 
where type='FooType' 
group by alternate_id order by created_at desc limit 10;
```

but this seems to be causing problems (failing to return rows with alternate_ids that are definitely in the top 10).  Any ideas how I should do this properly?

* SOLUTION ***
*(I can't post an answer as I'm a new user)*

here's what I've ended up doing:

```
SELECT field1,
...,
max(created_at),
...,
fieldN
FROM track_history_items
where type='FooType'
group by alternate_id
order by created_at desc
limit 10
```

This seems to do the trick.  Thought I'd post it here in case it's of use to others, or there are any mistakes with it that someone might spot!

Comment: use distinct: SELECT DISTINCT id FROM ....

Comment: Julio: but I need to select the whole row, not just the distinct alternate_id's

Comment: BTW adding the `max` to the select is documented to work on SQLite as mentioned at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17277152/sqlite-select-distinct-of-one-column-and-get-the-others/71924314#71924314

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`GROUP BY` must be used with aggregate functions (like sum, avg, ...).

You can use:

```
SELECT
  DISTINCT alternate_id,
  field1, -- one value per alternate_id
  ...,    -- one value per alternate_id
  fieldn  -- one value per alternate_id
FROM
  track_history_items
WHERE
  type = 'FooType'
ORDER BY
  created_at DESC
LIMIT 10
```

This is standard SQL.

It does not mean you will necessarily unique value in your alternat_id column. You will have every combinations of {alternate_id, fieldi}.

Comment: if you put distinct first it will check for distinct _combinations_ of the columns, not just distinct alternate_id.

Comment: Yes, now you have to delete the fields associated to alternate_id with more than one value and join it to another select to get additional data.

Answer (score 0):

In SQLite if you do do `SELECT max(anything) GROUP BY alternate_id`, magic SQLite extension behavior guarantees that you will get the full row accessible as mentioned at: [SQLite - SELECT DISTINCT of one column and get the others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17277152/sqlite-select-distinct-of-one-column-and-get-the-others/71924314#71924314) which is why your query would work on SQLite. The `order by created_at desc` can be removed:

```
SELECT max(created_at), field1, fieldN
FROM track_history_items
where type='FooType'
group by alternate_id
limit 10
```

It would however fail on PostgreSQL.

On PostgreSQL you could use `SELECT DISTINCT ON(alternate_id)`. Unlike just `SELECT DISTINCT` (without `ON` as mentioned at https://stackoverflow.com/a/5803116/895245 ), the `ON` PostgreSQL extension allows you to separately select "what you want to get back" and "what you want to be unique". Without `ON`, you get unique full tuples, which could repeat `alternate_id`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON(alternate_id),
  "field1",
  "fieldN"
FROM track_history_items
where type='FooType'
order by created_at desc
limit 10
```

See also: [What is the difference between Postgres DISTINCT vs DISTINCT ON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50846722/what-is-the-difference-between-postgres-distinct-vs-distinct-on)

Finally, another option is to use the `ROW_NUMBER` window function, which now works tested on both PostgreSQL 14.3 and SQLite 3.34.0 as in:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
        PARTITION BY "alternate_id"
        ORDER BY "created_at" DESC
      ) AS "rnk",
      *
    FROM "track_history_items"
    WHERE "name" IN ('a', 'b', 'c')
  ) sub
WHERE
  "sub"."rnk" = 1
ORDER BY
  "sub"."name" ASC,
  "sub"."population" DESC
```

As mentioned at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71924314/895245 that form allows for great versatility.