# How to SELECT DISTINCT of one column and get the others?

Tags: sqlite, select, distinct

I have a table like this (but with more columns):

| Code | Quantity |
| --- | --- |
| 00001 | 1 |
| 00002 | 1 |
| 00002 | 1 |
| 00002 | 2 |
| 00003 | 2 |
| 00003 | 1 |

And I want to get the same result as with `SELECT DISTINCT Code FROM table` (00001,00002,00003) but with all of the other table columns.

If I perform `SELECT DISTINCT Code, Quantity from table`
I get:

| Code | Quantity |
| --- | --- |
| 00001 | 1 |
| 00002 | 1 |
| 00002 | 2 |
| 00003 | 1 |
| 00003 | 2 |

But I would like to get:

| Code | Quantity |
| --- | --- |
| 00001 | 1 |
| 00002 | 1 |
| 00003 | 1 |

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Assuming you are using MySQL (as the question is tagged), the following will return an arbitrary value for the other columns:

```
select *
from t
group by code;
```

However, the particular values being selected come from indeterminate rows.

Comment: The question is for SQLite; the answer is the same regardless.

Answer (score 12):

**SQLite deterministic `min`/`max`**

To also guarantee that you will get the row with minimal quantity deterministically as in the desired output, you can simply add it as `min(quantity)` to the select as in:

```
select *, min(quantity)
from t
group by code;
```

As mentioned at: [row with max value per group - SQLite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48326957/row-with-max-value-per-group-sqlite)

SQLite docs guarantee that this works https://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html#bareagg

> Special processing occurs when the aggregate function is either min() or max(). Example:
>
> ```
> SELECT a, b, max(c) FROM tab1 GROUP BY a;
> ```
>
> When the min() or max() aggregate functions are used in an aggregate query, all bare columns in the result set take values from the input row which also contains the minimum or maximum.

This is an SQL extension and not portable across RDMSs.

**PostgreSQL `DISTINCT ON`**

In PostgreSQL  13.5 you can't GROUP by columns that are not either aggregates or PRIMARY: [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group)

But PostgreSQL has the `SELECT DISTINCT ON` extension which solves the use case nicely: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/sql-select.html#SQL-DISTINCT as it allows you to specify separately what needs to be distinct and what needs to be returned:

```
select distinct on (code) *
from t
group by code
order by code ASC, quantity ASC
```

This query would also deterministically pick the entries with lowest quantity, since `order by` is respected when choosing which column to pick.

`SELECT DISTINCT ON` was WONTFIXed in SQLite: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/22696 While this simple case can be achieved by both DBMSs, `SELECT DISTINCT` is simply more general than SQLite's magic min/max currently, e.g. it can handle multiple columns which SQLite says is not possible with its implementation.

**`RANK` and `ROW_NUMBER` window functions work for both SQLite and PostgreSQL**

This method is the most versatile I've seen so far, and the exact same code works on both SQLite and PostgresSQL:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
        PARTITION BY "name"
        ORDER BY "population" DESC
      ) AS "rnk",
      *
    FROM "table"
    WHERE "name" IN ('a', 'b', 'c')
  ) sub
WHERE "sub"."rnk" = 1
ORDER BY
  "sub"."name" ASC,
  "sub"."population" DESC
```

That exact same code works on both:

- SQLite 3.34.0
- PostgreSQL 14.3, e.g. it also answers the PostgreSQL: [PostgreSQL - fetch the rows which have the Max value for a column in each GROUP BY group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/586781/postgresql-fetch-the-rows-which-have-the-max-value-for-a-column-in-each-group/59298346#59298346)

Furthermore, we can easily modify that query to cover the following related use cases:

- if you replace `ROW_NUMBER()` with `RANK()`, it returns all ties for the `max` if more than one row reaches the max
- if you replace `"sub"."rnk" = 1` with `"sub"."rnk" <= n` you can get the top n per group rather than just the top 1

We are required to do a subquery in our code, you can't `WHERE "sub"."rnk" = 1` from inside the same query where you are doing `ROW_NUMBER`: [Window functions partition and order without subquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58263077/window-functions-partition-and-order-without-subquery)

Answer (score 6):

Building up on Gordon's answer, you can order a sub-query so that the group by will always return the lowst quantity for each code.

```
select *
from (select * from t order by code desc, quantity asc)
group by code;
```

Comment: The subquery is not needed for SQLite which magically guarantees that `min` and `max` will return the matching column: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71924314/895245