# How to select unique rows from a query that returns multiple duplicate records?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a scenario where a table contains a hash and a file path where there are files with identical content but the different metadata in different rows. I'd like to generate a list consisting of one file + path per hash, using sqlite SQL only.

Example:

```
hash    filename    path
abc123  foo.txt     /tmp/
abc123  bar.txt     /tmp/
xyz890  image.png   /home/user4
xyz890  image2.png  /home/user2
```

Ideal output would be:

```
abc123 /tmp/foo.txt
xyz890 /tmp/image2.png
```

What's the best way to do that?

Comment: How does that ideal output make sense? You can certainly combine the hash, but where did bar.txt, image.png, /home/user2, and /home/user4 go?

Comment: Perhaps a better way to express it is that I only need to know the first result for each hash.

Comment: `select hash, filename, path from table group by hash` may work? But the filename/path value could be any that match the hash (as per answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17277152/sqlite-select-distinct-of-one-column-and-get-the-others)

If not something simple like:

`SELECT hash, min(filename), path from table` should work.

Comment: The ideal output doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output shows you need first record for the first hash and the second line for the second hash. Based on what you've wrote in the beginning I suppose the output would be similar to

```
abc123 /tmp/foo.txt
xyz890 /tmp/image.png
```

You can get the result you need using the correlated subquery

```
select hash, path 
  from your_table t1
 where (t1.path, t1.filename) = (select path, filename 
                                   from your_table t2 
                                  where t2.hash = t1.hash limit 1)
```

At least it did work against data you've provided us with