# Pagination with distinct clause using hibernate and SQL Server

Tags: java, sql-server, spring, hibernate

I am creating a pageable query over SQL Server using JPA with Spring Data
using this repository call:

```java
    @Query("select distinct nat from TABE1 nat " +
            "left join TABLE2 natr on natr.ID= nat.ID" +
            "left join TABLE3 rec on rec.ID= natr.ID_" +
            "left join TABLE4 ew on ew.ID= rec.ID_ " +
            "where (ew.status = 'VA' or nat.isM = true) " +
            "and nat.expDate = :endTime " +
            "and nat.dDate = :endTime"
    )
    Page<Entity1> findAllActiveH(@Param("endTime") LocalDateTime endOfTime,
                                                     Pageable pageable);
```

Next is the generated query with hibernate

```
    select
        distinct t.id as id1_47_,
        t.creation_date as...
        ...ALL column
    from
        TABLE t 
    left outer join
     ..... ALL Joint 
    where
       Conditions...
    order by 1,
        case 
            when t.creation_date is null then 1 
            else 0 
        end,
        t.creation_date desc,
        case 
            when lower(t.id) is null then 1 
            else 0 
        end,
        lower(t.id) asc offset 0 rows fetch next 10 rows only
```

The generated query append several 'order by' regarding the pageable object but that throw the following exception

> ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if SELECT DISTINCT is specified

and I can't remove the distinct to avoid data duplication
any idea how to deal with pagination and distinct in spring data / hibernate and SQL Server?

Thanks

Comment: is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51310878/how-select-distinct-value-with-pageable-spring-data-jpa) related?

Comment: @Erwin, I am using JPQL and not native SQL query